# How can I get a reference to the server side form control from inside a web part?

Tags: 2010, master-page

I have a web part embedded in a publishing site that needs to get a reference to the `<form runat="server"/>` in the master page.

I have to set the 'action' attribute to allow the form to post outside of the site.

Instead of trying every combination of this.Page.Master and this.Parent.Page.Master - I wonder if someone has accomplished this?

Currently I have:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm)this.Parent.Page.Master.FindControl("aspnetForm");
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = Page.Form;
```

worked for me.

Comment: Of course! Perfect, thanks. Much easier than trying to navigate through the SP object hierarchy.

Comment: Well, the find control part works, but the settings of the form action doesn't seem to work. This is definitely possible in .net 3.5, and I tried this exact thing in webforms outside of sharepoint. Does sharepoint prevent this?

Comment: Yes, that's SharePoint specific. Until today I haven't found a workaround for that behavior.

Comment: PostBackUrl didn't seem to work either. Oh, Sharepoint, always trying to complicate things. I guess javascript is the only solution here.